# How to make computed read text by my own voice?

Tags: windows, voice

I've heard a lot that there are great frameworks for Text-To-Speach created. I would like to have the following:

- I would like my computed read ebooks by my own voice
- I don't want to create my own NN or something like that

Ideally I would like to have free Windows framework, prepare X hours of sound files with my voice reading known texts, load all this to framework and wait until it is ready for reading.

Not sure if it is available today - but if you could suggest something it would be great.

Comment: What operating systems? Price range? Do you need it to work with an existing TTS package or would a new one be OK? What format ebooks?

Comment: It is for my own to play around. So Windows as OS and free software if possible. I am not sure about ebooks format. I think I can use any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mary TTS](https://github.com/marytts/marytts) is an Open Source, Free, Text to Speech Java based package that runs on multiple platforms and includes a facility to generate your own voice packages.

- You can *potentially* simply read and record a few hours worth of your favored type of material **but** then to follow the proces, [here](https://github.com/marytts/marytts/wiki/VoiceImportToolsTutorial), you would have to split the recordings up into .wav files of a sentence or just a few words *it does not work too well on long blocks* and provide a matching  transcription for each file and there is a reasonable chance that you would be lacking at least some phonomes.
- You can use a set of predefined training scripts, *adapted from those provided by [HTS](http://hts.sp.nitech.ac.jp/)* as detailed [here](https://github.com/marytts/marytts/wiki/HMMVoiceCreation) - this has the advantages of the transcriptions already being available, the fragments being the correct lengths & the phonome coverage being good but are not necessarily fun to read.

Looking at the process involved the majority of the tools required **for voice creation** are Linux *or OS-X* based and there is not much mention of Windows but once the voice is created you can [transfer](https://github.com/marytts/marytts/wiki/Publishing-a-MARY-TTS-Voice) it to a Windows installation.

I have to admit that I do not know off of the top of my head the process for using it with an ebook.